# How to see the total number of winget packages?

Tags: windows, package, winget

## So i was wondering how much packages do i have that at least is available on winget and installed on my machine.

For example, `(winget list) -match ' winget$'` shows us all the winget packages installed even if its not installed through winget. But i want to know the total of this, without counting. Is there a way to do that? Oh and Im using Windows 11 Home Single Language.

Im expecting it to show the total available in winget packages. It would be great if it didnt show any of that "Secuity Update", "Update" and all that weird things. Basically i want to see this if i had 50 packages:
`50`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--source` option.

In particular (using PowerShell):

```
@(winget list --source winget).Count
```